# An example of a sequence $\left \{ a_n \right \}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

An example of a sequence $\left \{ a_n \right \}$   such that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=\infty$, but  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n+k} -a_n=0$ for each fixed posvitive integer $k$.

since $2^n, \ln(n), \frac{e^{2n}}{n}$ are sequences with limit of this sequence  is $\infty$ is any one satisfies the above property

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $a_n=H_n=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\frac1\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

The only one
of your three sequence
that satisfies
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n+k} -a_n=0
$
is
$\ln(n)$.

This is true because
$\ln(n+k)-\ln(n)
=\ln(1+k/n)
< k/n
\to 0
$
(since
$\ln(1+x) < x$).

For $2^n$,
$2^{n+k}-2^n
=2^n(2^k-1)
\to \infty
$
for any
$k > 0$.

For
$s_n=\frac{e^{2n}}{n}
$,
you can similarly show that
$s_{n+k}-s_n \to \infty$
for any $k > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\sqrt n \to \infty,$ and for each fixed $k,$

$$\sqrt {n+k} - \sqrt {n} = \frac{k}{\sqrt {n+k} + \sqrt {n}} \to 0.$$